# _CrtCheckMemory before and after function return

Tags: heap-memory, heap-corruption

following code:

```
_CrtCheckMemory();
vector<Vector3> samples = PoissonDisk::generate_poisson(m_resX-1, m_resY-1, minDist, 30, m_samples);
_CrtCheckMemory();
int s = samples.size();
```

the debugger traps into the heapcheck function in the second _CrtCheckMemory() telling me there's something wrong with the heap - so my assumption is that my generate_poisson function is doing a mess.
however - if i add a _CrtCheckMemory(); call directly at the end of the generate_poisson function, right before return, then the debugger still traps on the same line as before, not on the newly added _CrtCheckMemory()

what could this mean?

thanks!

//edit:
could it be possible that another thread is messing up the heap, or does _CrtCheckMemory() only check the heap of the current thread?

Answer (score 0):

Could mean your "Vector3" class is the real mess.  Check its constructor.

Comment: hi!
my Vector3 class just stores 3 doubles and has some functions for basic math. no pointer code, no allocations, nothing. i put a _CrtCheckMemory(); into the constructor of Vector3 but it still traps at the other location

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the copy constructor of Vector3
2. What is the return type of generate_poisson?  If it is returning a *reference* to a local variable, bad things will happen.
3. Yes, it could be that another thread is messing up the heap (the heap is not per-thread), but I would not expect that to be deterministic (unless you release a mutex which allows a higher priority thread to run).

Answer (score 0):

Or in the PoissonDisk::generate_poisson function something has been deleted when the scope changed( function ends ).